calculate $\nabla_{r'}\frac{1}{|r-r'|}$ in $\mathbb R^3$ in 2 ways
the first method I used is by substitution
$\nabla_{r'}\frac{1}{|r-r'|}=(\partial_{r'_1}\frac{1}{|r-r'|},\partial_{r'_2}\frac{1}{|r-r'|},\partial_{r'_3}\frac{1}{|r-r'|})$
now $s=r-r'\rightarrow =(-\partial_{s_1}\frac{1}{|s|},-\partial_{s_2}\frac{1}{|s|},-\partial_{s_3}\frac{1}{|s|})=-\nabla_{s}\frac{1}{|s|}$
the second is by chain rule $\nabla_{r'}\frac{1}{|r-r'|}=\nabla_{x}\frac{1}{|x|}_{|x=r-r'}\nabla_{r'}{r-r'}=\frac{\hat(r-r')}{|r-r'|^2}(-1)$   where the last one is the vector of full $-1$
are they right ?

It should be $\frac{s}{|s|^3}$ or, in terms of a unit vector, $\frac{\widehat{s}}{s^2}$. I'm not sure what you mean by a vector of full $-1$, but $\widehat{r-r'}$ is already a vector, so you don't want an extra vector factor in the result.

@J.G. yes it is right , it should be minus identity matrix ?

Since you want a gradient of a function of $|s|^2$, my advice is to take the gradient of $|s|^2$ then use the chain rule. There's no need to work with matrices. You can prove $\nabla_sf(|s|)=f'(|s|)\widehat{s}$.
